# How to finetune torchvision.models.detection.ssd300_vgg16?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, fine-tuning

I need to fine tune object detect algorithms using pytorch. All available tutorials do instance segmentation. Any guides or code examples on loading:
model=torchvision.models.detection.ssd300_vgg16(pretrained=False) and training it to a new set of images, bounding boxes, and labels. Using the google collaborate environment with the latest pytorch version
Thanks